# How do I set a custom background when using the LGViewHUD control?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I'm using the [LGViewHUD custom control](https://github.com/y0n3l/LGViewHUD) to display a HUD in my iOS application. How can I set a custom background for this HUD?

An example of this behavior can be found here:

[image: Custom HUD]

Comment: it's probably the bad way to do it, but why don't you just add a semi-transparent gradient?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your UIView `-drawRect:` method

```
        size_t locationsCount = 2;
        CGFloat locations[2] = {0.0f, 1.0f};
        CGFloat colors[8] = {0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.75f}; 
        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(colorSpace, colors, locations, locationsCount);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

        CGPoint center = CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height/2);
        float radius = MIN(self.bounds.size.width , self.bounds.size.height) ;
        CGContextDrawRadialGradient (context, gradient, center, 0, center, radius, kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);
        CGGradientRelease(gradient);
```

this was taken from [here](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD/blob/master/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD.m) (line 189)